# Linq query with multiple Contains/Any for RavenDB

Tags: c#, linq, ravendb

I have a document class that contains a list of "tags". Something like:

```
class Item {
  string Name { get; set; }
  List<string> Tags {get; set;}
}
```

Now I would like to create a query for RavenDB that hands me all items filtered by a list of tags. When using Entity Framework I managed to do this by something like this:

```
var query = GetQueryable();
foreach (var tag in tags)
{
   query = query.Where(i => i.Tags.Contains(tag));
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work with RavenDB, most likely because Contains isn't supported..  I've also tried rewriting it using Any, (`Where(i => i.Tags.Any(t=>t == tag))`) but that gives me a strange exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type
'System.Linq.Expressions.PrimitiveParameterExpression`1[System.String]'
to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression
```

Any great ideas? Am I doing this completely wrong?

Comment: What is `GetQueryable()` return type? and what are you doing in `query = query.Where(i => i.Tags.Contains(tag));`? what is the query type?

Comment: GetQueryable() returns an IQueryable<Item>. I do have access to the entire DocumentSession though, so that was just an example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Contains is indeed not yet supported (Perhaps it should be, but that's another matter entirely - we only really add support for various operators when its asked for)

As for multiple queries against Any, I assume you're trying to do dynamic data and you want to achieve something like

```
"X OR Y OR Z"
```

That's a tricky one, and the LINQ provider by default will aggregate those multiple WHERE clauses with AND, so your example looks like

```
"X AND Y AND Z"
```

Which will obviously never be the case.

Your best option for this one is to drop down to the Lucene query (at least for now) and do something like this:

```
var results = s.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Item>()
                   .Where(string.Format("Tags,:({0})", string.Join(" OR ", tags)));
```

Make sense?

The query above will look something like

```
"Tags,:(X OR Y OR Z)"
```

*Note: "Tags," informs RavenDB that Tags is an array*

Okay, [edit]!

The easiest way to get what you actually *want* is to do something along these lines

```
                new IndexDefinition<Item, Item>()
                {
                    Map = docs => from doc in docs
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Tags = doc.Tags
                                  },
                    Indexes = {{ x => x.Tags, FieldIndexing.Analyzed }}
                }.ToIndexDefinition(store.Conventions));
```

Then to query for your ands, you can do something like this:

```
                var results = s.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Item, WhateverYouCalledThatIndex>()
                   .Where(string.Format("Tags:({0})", string.Join(" AND ", tags)));
```

Now, things to be aware of

```
       Tags = doc.Tags
```

Will serialize that entire array into one giant blob, as it's just strings that will work for this example.

I am looking at better ways of expressing this, it is unlikely that we'll come up with a LINQ-ish way of doing this, as it doesn't really map across very well - but it *is* an answer that will work :)

I think I'd quite like to be able to at least do

```
  Map = docs => from doc in docs
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Tags = String.Join(" ", doc.Tags)
                                  },
```

(This won't work so don't try it), but it is a bit more explicit about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Close, but no cigar! ;-) First of all, the version I use doesn't seem to work with the "Tags,:" syntax. However if I create a Tag class with a single property called Name (and use "Tags,Name:"), your solution works. But it doesn't do exactly what I need. I'd like it to return only those Items that have ALL of the tags in the tags list (not any one of the tags).

Comment: Okay, THAT is more difficult, how would you do that as a set based operation in a relational database? I think at this point you might actually have to create an index to merge those tags into a single field and specify the analyzer you you want, and use a Lucene query to say "All of these terms please"

Comment: Yeah, it's not very pretty in a relational DB either, but the code I wrote in the question actually works with Entity Framework. Not pretty though, and hardly very efficient (which was part of the reason I figured that maybe Raven would be able to do a better job).

Comment: Oh, and just to be clear - your solution works like a charm! Many thanks!

Comment: Is this still the way to go or is there a better approach?

Comment: there is a better answer now - to use .In<> operator. see more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899936/ravendb-how-to-query-with-multiple-search-terms#answer-7902851

Comment: @apostolov: that question is not the same problem. This is looking for a range of values on a List<string> property, not the simpler string property case.