# RavenDB: How to query with multiple search terms

Tags: ravendb

My entity is:

```cs
class Resource
{
    string Name;
    string EmployeeId;
}
```

How do I query for resources of multiple employees? I tried this:

```cs
Resource[] FindResourcesByEmployees(string[] employeeIds)
{
    return this.Session.Query<Resource>()
        .Where(r => employeeIds.Contains(r.EmployeeId))
        .ToArray();
}
```

However that gives me NotSupportedException: Method not supported: Contains. Then I tried the following method:

```cs
Resource[] FindResourcesByEmployees(string[] employeeIds)
{
    return this.Session.Query<Resource>()
        .Where(r => employeeIds.Any(v => v == r.EmployeeId))
        .ToArray();
}
```

That throws NotSupportedException: Expression type not supported: System.Linq.Expressions.TypedParameterException.

In SQL it would be something like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM resource WHERE employeeid IN (1, 2, 3)
```

My question is, how do I perform this query in RavenDB?

Comment: This post may help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207739/linq-query-with-multiple-contains-any-for-ravendb

Comment: Nope, that case regards the entity itself containing a collection. In my case only the query contains a collection, while the entity contains no collections.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can use the `In` operator. If I remember correctly your code should look like this:

```cs
using Raven.Client.Linq;

Resource[] FindResourcesByEmployees(string[] employeeIds)
{
    return this.Session.Query<Resource>()
        .Where(r => r.EmployeeId.In<string>(employeeIds)))
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: One more thing: the .In<>-extension method requires "using Raven.Client.Linq"